# Is the derivative of a differentiable Lipschitz function also Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

So assume $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is ***both*** differentiable everywhere ***and*** Lipschitz continuous, then is its derivative, $f'(x)$, also Lipschitz? I didn't manage to prove (or disprove) it and couldn't find an answer or a counter example after searching extensively.

If we further assume $f\in C^{\infty}$, then $f'$ is ***differentiable everywhere, bounded, and integrable, with a Lipschitz integral***. In this case, is $f'$ (and any function satisfying these four conditions) Lipschitz?

Comment: I think differentiable is a stronger condition then Lipschitz continuous. Thus just take a non Lipschitz continuous function and integrate it to get a counterexample.

Comment: If you mean *globally Lipschitz*, then no, consider $$f(x)=\int_0^x \sin(y^2)\,\mathrm dy$$ defined on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Oh yes, I forgot to mention that I was aware that the Fresnel integrals are both Lipschitz and differentiable, and I think it can be extended to more similar functions given by the answer below. But are there more "ordinary" functions that may serve as a counter example?

Comment: @Robert The fact that this integral has its own name shows, in my opinion, that it is fairly commonly used :)

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Consider the case where $f$ is $C^2$. Then, it is lipschitz continuous if, and only if, it's derivative is bounded. Similarly, $f'$ is lipschitz if, and only if, $f''$ is bounded.

However, we can find bounded smooth function with unbounded derivatives : let $\chi:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be smooth step function, ie $\chi$ takes value in $[0,1]$, $\chi(x)$ is $0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $1$ for $x\geq 1$. Then, set :
$$g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{2^n}\chi(4^n(x-n))$$

Since the sum is locally finite, $g$ is smooth and :
$$g'(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 2^n\chi'(4^n(x-n))$$
However, we have :$$\sup_\mathbb R g = \lim_{+\infty }g = 1 <+\infty$$
while, if $x\in[0,1]$ has $\chi'(x) >0$, then :
$$g'(x+n) = 2^n\chi'(x)$$
so $\sup_{\mathbb R} g' = +\infty$.

Therefore, if $f(x) = \int_0^xg(x) \text dx$, we see that $f$ is Lipschitz, smooth, but its derivative $f'=g$ is not Lipschitz.

Comment: But if sup($f'$) is infinity, then it's not bounded, so $f$ is not Lipschitz itself?

Comment: The first paragraph explains that finding a counter example to the OP reduces to finding a function $f'$ which is bounded but not Lipschitz. I changed my notations to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks! Could you also read the comment I made above; I wonder if there are more "ordinary" functions that may serve as a counter example?

Comment: I don' t think I will be able to find a counter example more "ordinary" than the one @MaximilianJanisch provided